# Designing single API for two different types

Tags: java, oop, generics, api-design

I've two lists:

```
List<Date> list1  = new ArrayList<Date>();
List<WDate> list2 = new ArrayList<WDate>();
```

I want to remove some objects from these lists. This functionality is present in a util class.

```
public static List<Date> removeFromList1(List<Date> dateList) 
{
    Iterator<Date> dateItr = dateList.iterator();
    while(dateItr.hasNext())
    {
        Date date = dateItr.next();
        if(date.compareTo(currentDate) <= 0)
            dateItr.remove();
    }

    return dateList;
}

public static List<WDate> removeFromList2(List<WDate> dateList) 
{
    Iterator<WDate> dateItr = dateList.iterator();
    while(dateItr.hasNext())
    {
        WDate date = dateItr.next();
        if(date.getDate().compareTo(currentDate) <= 0)
            dateItr.remove();
    }

    return dateList;
}

class WDate
{
    Date date;
    Date getDate() { return date;}
}
```

**How to create a single utility method to serve both the lists?**

Comment: You should know better than asking such a vague question.

Comment: Maybe provide some info about `A` and `B` and show a sample implementation of your methods.

Comment: You could use generics for the item type of the list

Comment: What do you mean by _wrapper_? Is it a sub class? Does it implement a shared interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> removeFromList(List<T> list, T current) 
{
    Iterator<T> itr = list.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        T elm = itr.next();
        if(elm.compareTo(current) <= 0)
            itr.remove();
    }

    return list;
}
```

...

```
class WDate implements Comparable<WDate>
{
    Date date;
    Date getDate() { return date;}

    public WDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(WDate other) {
        return date.compareTo(other.date);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

If you want to avoid implementing the Comparable interface, you can supply a Comparator to removeFromList:

```
public static <T> List<T> removeFromList(List<T> list, T current,
        Comparator<T> comp) {
    Iterator<T> itr = list.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        T elm = itr.next();
        if(comp.compare(elm, current) <= 0)
            itr.remove();
    }
    return list;
}
```

UPDATE 2 (for davidxxx)

```
public static List<Date> removeFromList1(List<Date> dateList) 
{
    return removeFromList(dateList, currentDate.getDate());
}

public static List<WDate> removeFromList2(List<WDate> dateList) 
{
    return removeFromList(dateList, currentDate);
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea but it has some limits. You provide a new parameter which is originally located in the utility class. This parameter represents the actual date. Adding this parameter makes some internal data to become visible to the client. Besides, it forces the client to add this second parameter at each call. At last, if bad used, the user could provide another date, which could be  not suitable.

Comment: @davidxxx OK, I see the extra flexibility as an advantage. You can always add helper functions that will call this one.

Comment: In your helper method, you should make a `if else if` to send a current date with the suitable type : `Date` or `WDate` since you should call`compare()` method with the specific instance if you want that the comparison works.

Comment: Not necessarily: I would make currentDate a WDate instead of a Date, and call the method either with currentDate, or with currentDate.getDate()

Comment: @MauricePerry thanks for the idea. With slight modification, working well. thumbs up!!

Comment: Of course you can but here again, you will have to perform a `if else if` somewhere in the code to identify if it a `Date` or `WDate` instance to call the method with `currentDate` or `currentDate.getDate()`

Comment: @davidxxx not at all

Answer (score 1):

As you cannot introduce a common interface for the two types of Date (`java.util.date` being not modifiable), you cannot have a single method which would have the safety brought by a fine generics use : the single common ancestor is `Object`...
Personally, I think that you should keep the two methods which is the cleanest way with your constraints.
Why ? I will try to explain risks.
If you use a single method, as said, you coud not have type safety and you will increase responsibilities of your helper method since it should perform a type check before to be able to do its processings.

For example, you can do :

```
public static <T> List<T> removeFromList(List<T> dateList) {

  Iterator<T> dateItr = dateList.iterator();

  while (dateItr.hasNext()) {
    T date = dateItr.next();

    // check if null value otherwise illegalArgumentexception may be thrown
    if (date == null) {
       continue;
    }

    // check types
    boolean isEquals = false;
    if (date instanceof Date) {
      if (currentDate.equals(date)) {
        isEquals = true;
      }
    }
    else if (date instanceof WDate) {
      WDate wDate = (WDate) date;
      if (currentDate.equals(wDate.getDate())) {
        isEquals = true;
      }
    }
    // if unexpected type, we rise an exception
   else {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("type not supported=" + date.getClass());
    }    

   //perform removing
   if (isEquals){
      dateItr.remove();
    }
  }

   return dateList;
}
```

and now you call the method like this :

```
List<WDate> wdates = new ArrayList<>();
WDate wdate = new WDate();
wdates.add(wdate);
removeFromList(wdates);
```

The problem is that you can the method with any type in the List now :

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
String string = new String();
strings.add(string);
removeFromList(strings);
```

So some errors which could be detected at compile time, will be only discovered at runtime when the `IllegalArgumentException` will be raised.